# The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. Django docker

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, environment-variables, travis-ci

i tried to find solution on stack and other websites but without result. Im fighting with django for some days.

I got my django app dockerized and it works fine. I'm using .env file to serve secret variables. And here start the problem. I can't use travis CI or debug mode in Visual Studio Code becouse my env variables are not visible. When im trying to run travis or debuger, im getting error "The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty". The question is, how to properly configure my django app or docker instance to use env variables in every situation? Some days ago i tried to write secret_key without hidding it, but my debuger is failing on connection with database, so it seems that my variables are not visible at all. But as i said, when i run my app in normal mode or as a docker instance it works fine, my .env file is visible for django. Here you can find my settings.py

```
from os.path import join, dirname
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages


dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SEC_KEY')
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': 5432

    }
}
```

And here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  electronicshop:
    image: electronicshop
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/electronic_shop
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    # env_file:
    #   - .env
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=&{DB_PASSWORD}
      - DEBUG=1
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5454:5454/tcp
```

Comment: firtst fill the secret key manually and check is other parameters are comming and things working fine

Comment: are you using python_dotenv? and if yes, make sure you have `load_dotenv()` in your settings.py

Comment: @sarangkkl as i said, i wrote secret key manually but in debug mode. Django was screaming that database credentials are wrong, so it seems like env variables are not visible in debug mode or trevis CI. Also i dont want to make push to my github settings with secret key.

Comment: @reppon yes, im using load_dotenv(). Updated my setting.py in my post.

Answer (score 0):

In addiction to the answer above:
just add new line for SECRET_KEY variable like that:

```
environment:
  - DB_HOST=db
  - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
  - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
  - DB_PASS=${DB_PASSWORD}
  - DEBUG=1
  - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY_VARIABLE_NAME_FROM_ENV_FILE}
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. I had to add secret_key to docker-compose environment.

Comment: how did you do it?

Comment: You must update your answer to explain how you did done it